# How do the stream manipulators work?

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

It is well known that the user can define stream manipulators like this:

```
ostream& tab(ostream & output)
{
    return output<< '\t';
}
```

And this can be used in *main()* like this:

```
cout<<'a'<<tab<<'b'<<'c'<<endl;
```

Please explain me how does this all work? If *operator<<* assumes as a second parameter a pointer to the function that takes and returns **ostream &**, then please explain my why it is necessary? What would be wrong if the function does not take and return **ostream &** but it was *void* instead of *ostream &*?

Also it is interesting why “dec”, “hex” manipulators take effect until I don’t change between them, but user defined manipulators should be always used in order to take effect for each streaming?

Comment: Can you clarify the question in your last paragraph? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean That if you write cout<<hex<<a<<b<<endl<<c; then all numbers are shown in hex base, but if I write cout<<'a'<<tab<<'b'<<'c'<<endl;, then the "tab" with take effect only while printing 'b', but not for 'c'.

Comment: @Narek: Your definition of `tab` just prints a tab, it doesn't alter the stream's settings like `hex` does.

Comment: Ok, you are right! But what is the reason for ostream& tab(ostream & output) to take a param as ostream& but not void?

Comment: If it had a different signature, it wouldn't match the overloaded `operator<<` that `ostream` contains for function pointers so it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is error. The problem is whay there is no variant with void. Because I don't see the use of the argument. So I guess it could be in standard and it would work, isn't it? Is the argument necessary? Is it being used or it is written because there is no variant with void argument?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if it didn't take the `ostream` as argument, the function body would have no reference to the stream object on which to operate which would make it difficult for it to do anything.

Comment: Ok, great. Then how the arguemt is being passed if I write cout<<tab<<'a'; but not cout<<tab(cout)<<'a'; ?

Comment: Look at the definition of the `operator<<` overload, it passes itself to the manipulator. "Returns: `pf(*this)`." `std::cout << tab(cout)` would be wrong as it would be trying to call an `op<<` taking two `ostream`. The `op<<` we are talking about takes a function pointer, not the result of calling a function.

Comment: Oh, sure.  Thanks a lot, I was really confused. I accept your answer because I take into accout this discussion as well!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The standard defines the following `operator<<` overload in the `basic_ostream` class template:

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(
    basic_ostream<charT,traits>& (*pf) (basic_ostream<charT,traits>&) );
```

> Effects: None. Does not behave as a formatted output function (as described in 27.6.2.5.1).
>
> Returns: `pf(*this)`.

The parameter is a pointer to a function taking and returning a reference to a `std::ostream`.

This means that you can "stream" a function with this signature to an `ostream` object and it has the effect of calling that function on the stream. If you use the name of a function in an expression then it is (usually) converted to a pointer to that function.

`std::hex` is an `std::ios_base` manipulator defined as follows.

```
   ios_base& hex(ios_base& str);
```

> Effects: Calls `str.setf(ios_base::hex, ios_base::basefield)`.
>
> Returns: str.

This means that streaming `hex` to an `ostream` will set the output base formatting flags to output numbers in hexadecimal. The manipulator doesn't output anything itself.

Comment: I thought the question was, "how come manipulators themselves aren't defined to return `void`, and the `operator<<` overload for manipulators defined to call `pf(*this)` and then return `*this`"?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I thought the question was: "Please explain me how does this all work?". It works because that `basic_ostream` defines that particular overload and that's why the given signature is required. I didn't follow the question in the last paragraph, though.

Comment: Oh, OK. I usually read these questions as "what is the motivation for the standard?" rather than "what does the standard say?", but maybe that's just because I have a copy of the standard I can read for myself, and fail to empathise with those who don't ;-)

Answer (score 11):

There is nothing wrong with it except there is no overloaded << operator defined for it. The existing overloads for << are expecting a manipulator with the signature **ostream& (*fp)(ostream&)**.

If you gave it a manipulator with the type **ostream& (*fp)()** you would get a compiler error since it **does not** have a definition for **operator<<(ostream&, ostream& (*fp)())**. If you wanted this functionality you would have to overload the << operator to accept manipulators of this type.

You would have to write a definition for this: 
**ostream& ostream::operator<<(ostream& (*m)())**

Keep in mind here that nothing magical is happening here. The stream libraries rely heavily on *standard* C++ features: operator overloading, classes, and references.

Now that you know how you can create the functionality you described, here's why we don't:

Without passing a reference to the stream we are trying to manipulate, we can't make modifications to the stream connected to the final device (cin, out, err, fstream, etc). The function (modifiers are all just functions with fancy names) would either have to return a new ostream that had nothing to do with the one to the left of the << operator, or through some very ugly mechanism, figure out which ostream it should connect with else everything to right of the modifier won't make it to the final device, but would rather be sent to whatever ostream the function/modifier returned.

Think of streams like this

```
cout << "something here" << tab << "something else"<< endl;
```

really means

```
(((cout << "something here") << tab ) << "something else" ) << endl);
```

where each set of parentheses does something to cout (write, modify etc) and then returns cout so the next set of parentheses can work on it.

If your tab modifier/function did not take a reference to an ostream it would have to somehow guess what ostream was to the left of the << operator to perform its task. Were you working with cour, cerr, some file stream...? The internals of the function will never know unless they are handed that information somehow, and why not that how to be as simple as a reference to it.

Now to really drive the point home, let's look at what **endl** really is and which overloaded version of the << operator we are using:

This operator looks like this:

```
  ostream& ostream::operator<<(ostream& (*m)(ostream&)) 
  {  
      return (*m)(*this);
  }
```

endl looks like this:

```
  ostream& endl(ostream& os)      
  {  
      os << '\n'; 
      os.flush();     
      return os;
  }
```

The purpose of endl is to add a newline and flush the stream, making sure all the contents of the stream’s internal buffer have been written to the device. In order to do this, it first needs to write a '\n' to this stream. It then needs to tell the stream to flush. The only way for endl to know which stream to write to and flush is for the operator to pass that information to the endl function when it calls it. It'd be like me telling you to wash my car, but never tell you which car is mine in the full parking lot. You'd never be able to get your job done. You need me to either hand you my car, or I can wash it myself.

I hope that clears things up

PS - If you do happen to accidentally find my car, please wash it.

Answer (score 4):

Normally the stream manipulator sets some flags (or other settings) on the stream object, so that next time it is used, it will act according to the flags. The manipulator therefore returns the same object its passed. The `operator<<` overload that called the manipulator already has this object, of course, so as you noticed, the return value isn't strictly needed for that case. I think this covers all the standard manipulators - they all return their input.

However, with the return value, the framework is flexible enough that a custom stream manipulator *could* return a different object, presumably a wrapper for the object its given. This other object would then be returned from `cout << 'a' << tab`, and could do something that the built-in `ostream` formatting settings don't support.

Not sure how you'd arrange for this other object to be freed, though, so I don't know how practical this is. It might have to be something peculiar, like a proxy object that's managed by the `ostream` itself. Then the manipulator would only work for custom stream classes that actively support it, which isn't usually the point of manipulators.