# How to write user-defined manipulators for streaming self-written class

Tags: c++, iostream

How do I write user-defined stream manipulators in C++ that control the format of streaming a self-written class?

Specifically, how would I write simple manipulators `verbose` and `terse` to control the amount of output streamed?

My environment is GCC, versions 4.5.1 and up.

Example:

```
class A
{
 ...
};

A a;

// definition of manipulators verbose and terse

cout << verbose << a << endl; // outputs a verbosely
cout << terse << a << endl; // outputs a tersely
```

PS: What follows is just a side question, feel free to ignore it: Can this portably be extended to manipulators taking arguments? Josuttis writes in "The C++ Standard Library" near the end of section 13.6.1 that writing manipulators taking argument is implementation dependent. Is this still true?

Comment: Not a duplicate but a related (interesting) topic : [How do the stream manipulators work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633864/how-do-the-stream-manipulators-work)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason for them to be implementation dependent.

This is comething that I use, for the actual manipulator, create a function that returns an instance of the following helper. If you need to store the data, just store it inside the helper, some global variable, singleton, etc...

```
    /// One argument manipulators helper
    template < typename ParType >
    class OneArgManip
    {
        ParType par;
        std::ostream& (*impl)(std::ostream&, const ParType&);

        public:
            OneArgManip(std::ostream& (*code)(std::ostream&, const ParType&), ParType p) 
                : par(p), impl(code) {}

            // calls the implementation
            void operator()(std::ostream& stream) const
            { impl(stream,par); }

            // a wrapper that allows us to use the manipulator directly
            friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, 
                            const OneArgManip<ParType>& manip)
            { manip(stream); return stream; }
    };
```

Example of a manipulator based on this:

```
OneArgManip<unsigned> cursorMoveUp(unsigned c) 
{ return OneArgManip<unsigned>(cursorMoveUpI,c); }

std::ostream& cursorMoveUpI(std::ostream& stream, const unsigned& c)
{ stream << "\033[" << c << "A"; return stream; }
```

For some explanation:

1. u use the manipulator, that returns a new instance of the helper bound to an implementation of the helper
2. stream tries to process the helper, that invokes the `<<` overload on the helper
3. that invokes the `()` operator on the helper
4. that invokes the real implementation of the helper with the parameter passed from the original manipulator call

If you want I can post 2 param and 3 param helpers as well. The principle is the same though.

Comment: Thanks, however I was thinking of manipulators that affect how later items are streamed.

Comment: @Peter it's the same thing. You just store the setting somewhere. Instead of outputting something into the stream you set `YourClass::outputtype` or something similar.