# C++ << operator to and from a database

Tags: c++, database, output

I want to use `<<` and `>>` operator to load and save to an external database.
What would the external database have to implement for that to work?

Thoughts or experiences?
I am using SQL to interact with my sqlite3 database.

For instance, I want to say:

```
MyClass c;
c >> databaseInstance;
c << databaseInstance;
```

Comment: Well the << operator wants to operate on "streams". I can see that databases probably COULD SOMEHOW be exposed as streams... But what would you want to achieve by READING from a database instance? What should the db read?

Comment: its a very odd abstraction. >> and << work on stream-like things. A database is not a stream-like thing. Its more like a dictionary

Comment: No you don't. operator overloading is somethimng to make your code more succinct and clearer. If I saw theose operators used with a DB, it would be seen as terse and opaque.

Answer (score 3):

`databaseInstance` would need to be of some type that provides `operator>>` and `operator<<` functions that write to the database in the way that you want, thus providing a stream-like interface. These functions will be defined somewhat like so:

```
database_type& operator<<(database_type& databaseInstance, MyClass& c)
{
  // Write to database here
  return databaseInstance;
}

database_type& operator>>(database_type& databaseInstance, MyClass& c)
{
  // Read from database here
  return databaseInstance;
}
```

This makes use of [operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/150634). There's not much more to say than that and it's a pretty odd thing to do with a database as a database is not very much like a stream.

You probably want to reverse the usage of the operators for the sake of consistency with the C++ standard library:

```
MyClass c;
databaseInstance << c;
databaseInstance >> c;
```

However, it's uncertain exactly what the final line would read into your `MyClass` object. The second line only really makes sense if this `databaseInstance` has been configured to insert into a particular table.

Comment: Exactly what I thought. A database instance has so many things it could return, it doesn't really make sense in this way. Also: In which table, database, etc should it insert in the first case? I guess it could find out by reflecting the actual object, but still.

Comment: @MooingDuck Hope you feel better. :D

Answer (score 1):

hmm. interesting..

ok, I assume that you just want to select from the DB in the case of operator>> and insert/update in the case of operator<<. The trick here is knowing what columns to read/write to.

You could use a [stream manipulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633864/how-do-the-stream-manipulators-work) (like "hex" that turns an integer output into hex format) to determine which column to use, so you'd have something like

```
int c;
DBStreamInterface db(tableA);
c << columnA << db;
```

or you could define a struct type that had the same layout as a table, and read the entire row into it:

```
struct TableRow {
  int columnA;
  string columnB;
};
TableRow t << db;
```

but you'd have to be careful with matching the schema in the DB to the definition of the struct (unless you wanted to go go all-out in template code generation where you could create the appropriate struct by reading the schema DDL and dynamically allocating storage for each field in a class constructor).