# could you explain the reasons about output when using std::hex and std::wios::hex in C++

Tags: c++, hex, difference

I have three programs.
the code of programA is shown below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;
int _tmain( void )
{
    wstringstream s2;    
    TCHAR waTemp2[4] = {0xA0, 0xA1, 0x00A2, 0xA3};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
    s2<< hex <<(unsigned int)waTemp2[i] << " ";  
    }
    wstring strData2 =  s2.str();
    wcout << strData2.c_str() <<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

here is the output:

a0 a1 a2 a3

the code of programB is shown below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;
int _tmain( void )
{
    wstringstream s2;    
    TCHAR waTemp2[4] = {0xA0, 0xA1, 0x00A2, 0xA3};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
    s2<< hex << waTemp2[i] << " ";  
    }
    wstring strData2 =  s2.str();
    wcout << strData2.c_str() <<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

here is the output:

????

the code of the programC is shown below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wstringstream s2;    
    TCHAR waTemp2[4] = {0xA0, 0xA1, 0x00A2, 0xA3};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
    s2 << std::wios::hex <<(unsigned int)waTemp2[i] << " "; 
    }
    wstring strData2 =  s2.str();
    wcout<< strData2.c_str() <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

here is the output:

2048160 2048161 2048162 2048163

could you tell me the reasons the difference between std::wios::hex and std::hex, std::hex << waTemp2[i] and std::hex << (unsigned int)waTemp2[i] resulted in different of the output.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`std::hex` is a manipulator. It sets the stream to output hex when you pass an integer. It is equivalent to calling `setf(std::wios::hex,  std::wios::basefield);` on the stream (assuming wide streams). For example, try the following modification of your code. You should see the same results.

```
wchar_t waTemp2[4] = {0xA0, 0xA1, 0x00A2, 0xA3};
s2.setf(std::wios::hex, std::wios::basefield);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    s2 << (unsigned)waTemp2[i] << " ";  
}
```

`std::wios::hex` is a constant number used as a bitmask flag. Do not confuse it with a manipulator which sets the stream.
On [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=96209c8b6fd420715f03fcc6b78227f7-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51) for example the following prints `8`.

```
std::cout << std::wios::hex;
```

It is used as a bitmask to update the format flags on the stream. It will defined something like the following (see the real definition in libstdc++ [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01271_source.html#l00267)):

```
enum fmtflags
{
   _hex = 1L << 3,
};

class ios_base
{
    static const fmtflags hex = _hex;
};
```

The reason you are seeing `2048160 2048161 2048162 2048163` is it is just printing out the numbers of `std::wios::hex` and `(unsigned int)waTemp2[i]`. Add a space in between to see `s2 << std::wios::hex << " " << (unsigned int)waTemp2[i] << " ";`

The problem with `s2 << hex << waTemp2[i] << " ";` is `std::hex` is only used for integers. Since `wchar_t` is not an integer, it just prints the corresponding character.

Comment: @yaoike: What are the two questions?

Comment: thank you very much.
i still have three questions.
1. you said std::hex is a manipulator. It sets the stream to output hex when you pass an integer. 
why does it work when i pass an integer rather than TCHAR,i could not find std::hex manipulator can take integer in C++ reference[link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/?kw=hex).

2. To code `s2<< hex <<(unsigned int)waTemp2[i] << " ";`,is there any way to instead of it, in the `ios_base& hex (ios_base& str);` forms

Comment: 3. I didn't understand this sentence which you said。"However, the result are undefined because **0xA0**, etc. is greater than the number of bits in the value **std::wios::hex**.",
Is the number of bits in the value **std::wios::hex** equal 64? It doesn't work when I use **0x05** to replace **0xA0**, could you do an example?

Comment: @yaoike: 1) Your link clearly says so: `**integral numerical values** inserted into the stream are expressed in hexadecimal base `. 2) I'm not sure what you are asking, do you mean call it like a function `std::hex(std::wcout);`? 3) Sorry, I made a mistake, it isn't the bitwise left shift, it is just printing the number. For example, the `160` in `2048160` is just `0xA0` in decimal, and the same goes for the other ones (see my updated answer).

Comment: 2)yes. 3)OK,i am seeing **2048 160 2048 161 2048 162 2048 163** ,but why is **2048** rather than **8**, you said:
`enum fmtflags

{
   _hex = 1L << 3,
};

class ios_base
{
    static const fmtflags hex = _hex;
};`

Comment: @yaoike: What compiler are you using? The number `8` was for libstdc++ gcc only. **EDIT** Nevermind, I see you are using MSVC from `"stdafx.h"`. The number depends on the implementation (it is not set). [See here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags) and notice it says **implementation defined**.

Comment: @yaoike: [Like this example?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=9b8b3c55d8c7885354f4bb370eb274f9-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51). Sorry, I cannot fully understand.

Comment: No, Not **s2.operator<<(std::hex).operator<<((unsigned)waTemp2[i]);** ,like this **s2 << std::hex(ios_base& str)**. what is **std::hex**, a manipulator or [a function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/?kw=hex)?

Comment: @yaoike: This is getting long, but the important point is a stream manipulator **is a** function. Please read [How do the stream manipulators work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633864/how-do-the-stream-manipulators-work). When you do `s2 << std::hex` you are passing a pointer to a function to the `operator<<` which calls the function internally. You cannot call `std::hex` the way you have it.

Comment: Also, I don't mind trying to help, but if you have more questions. Please ask them as a separate question, but [here is an example of a custom manipulator](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4ea48c175179bd9410cfd05bb8d30bb4-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51). See how I made it a function and passed it to the stream?

Comment: I see. A thousand thanks for taking the time to answer these questions. :) This is my first question in here. I was so happy to ask my questions on this site.