# Why does cout.precision() affect the whole stream?

Tags: c++, iostream, std

I feel I'm asking a very basic question, but I haven't been able to find an answer here or in Google. I recall we were taught this at school, but alas it has vanished over years.

Why does `cout.precision()` (`std::ios_base::precision()`) affect the whole stream when called in the middle of the output list? I know the rule that `std::setprecision()` should be used to change precision on the fly, and that `cout.precision()` is going to spoil the output with the value it returns. But what is the mechanics of this? Is it due to buffering? The manuals state these "do the same thing", but empirically I can see it's not entirely true.

MCVE:

```
const double test = 1.2345;
cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
cout.precision(2);
cout << test << endl << cout.precision(3) <<  test << endl;

// Output:
// 1.234
// 21.234

// after the same init
cout.precision(2);
cout << test << endl << setprecision(3) <<  test << endl;

// Output
// 1.23
// 1.234
```

Is this "implementation specific / not defined by the standard"?
Feel free to mark this as duplicate, for I haven't been able to find it on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of function argument evaluation is unspecified. When you call `std::cout.precision(n)` the precision of `std::cout`' is set at the point this call is evaluated. In your expression

```
cout << test << endl << cout.precision(3) <<  test << endl;
```

the `cout.precision(3)` is, apparently, called first thing which the compiler is entirely allowed to do. Remember that the compiler considers the above statement equivalent to

```
std::cout.operator<<(test)
          .operator<<(std::endl)
          .operator<<(std::cout.preision(3))
          .operator<<(test)
          .operator<< (std::endl);
```

Practically, it seems for your compiler function arguments are evaluated right to left. Only then the different shift operators are executed. As a result, the precision gets changed before the output is done.

The use of manipulators like `std::setprecision(n)` avoids relying on the order subexpressions are evaluated: the temporary created from `std::setprecision(n)` is created whenever it is. The effect is then applied when the appropriate shift operator is called. Since the shift operators have to be called in the appropriate order, the use of the manipulator happens at a known place.

Comment: Great, so detailed! But is there a typo between the lines of code? Looks like one `operator<<()` calls is lost.

Comment: Also, do I understand correctly that the effect with `setprecision()` is exactly because it returns a temporary object, whose points of creation and invocation are separate in time?

Comment: @iksemyonov: I think all operator calls were there but one was actually wrong (it is actually also a member). Yes, `std::setprecision(n)` creates a temporary which is "inserted" into the stream using an `operator<<()` call. When this temporary is inserted no characters are written but the precision is changed. The creation and insertion time are different.

Answer (score 4):

The exact time when `cout.precision(3)` is evaluated in your first example is not defined, because its value serves as an argument for a function call. OTOH with the second example, the time when `setprecision(3)` is inserted to the stream is very well defined - i.e. after `endl` is inserted and before `test` (2nd time). Therefor the first version will not produce reliable results (what you get may be different on different implementations), but the second version will.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166907/is-there-a-sequence-point-between-a-function-call-returning-an-object-and-a-meth) for a more detailed explanation. (The question there doesn't use operators, but the principle is the same - calling a member function on the return value of another function.)

Comment: Used to have no idea about that! Reading.